# init is not called on object when using find

Tags: ember.js

so I am working on an XMPP client with Ember.js. Since my data is coming from XMPP I wanted to create my own models and found this nice tutorial: http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html and the small example application [emberreddit](https://github.com/eviltrout/emberreddit).

The setup should be pretty simple. I just extend Ember.Object and implement a find function which either creates or returns the object:

```
App.Conversation = Ember.Object.extend({
    messages: [],
    talkingPartner: null,

    init: function(){
        this._super();

        console.log("Init called for App.Conversation");

        //Binding for XMPP client event
        $.subscribe('message.client.im', _.bind(this._onMessage, this));
    },

    //Private Callbacks
    _onMessage: function(event, message){

        console.log("Received message");

        this.find(message.jid).messages.pushObject(message);
    }
});

App.Conversation = Ember.Object.reopenClass({

    store: {},

    find: function(id){
        if(!this.store[id]){
            this.store[id] = App.Conversation.create();
        }
        return this.store[id];
    }
});
```

This follows roughly the code from [here](https://github.com/eviltrout/emberreddit/blob/master/js/app.js#L41). It works okay but `init` is never called. If I create the object not using `find` it works. So I am a little confused.

- As far as I know `store` should be the same for all instances of
  `App.Conversation`. Is that correct? Also, if that is true I have to
  move `messages` and `talkingPartner` to `init` and set them via
  `this.set('message')`, don't I.
- Why is `ìnit` not called when `App.Conversateion.create()` is called in `App.Conversation.find(id)`. Can anyone explain why? I found that Ember.js sometimes behaves a little bit different than one expects at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
App.Conversation = Ember.Object.reopenClass({
```

To this:

```
App.Conversation.reopenClass({
```

You code is reopening Ember.Object itself, and the completely overwriting the definition of `App.Conversation`.

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekidd/xwE59/) based on your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was too obvious for me, I guess.